# R - aws.s3 - Amazon S3 Client error: (405) Method Not Allowed

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I am trying to use the [aws.s3](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/aws.s3/) package in R to access data on an Amazon S3 bucket. However, I run into problems:

```
bucket_exists( bucket = 's3://my-bucket-name' )
Client error: (405) Method Not Allowed
```

I have a key and secret that appear to authenticate properly; changing the key results in a 403 forbidden error. My region is set appropriately (eu-central-1).

I have no problems using the [AWS command line interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) with the same key/secret.

If anyone has had similar issues, please let me know your resolution.
Cheers

Comment: Consider enabling logging on your bucket.  Then you can go to the logs to try to determine what request is actually being made. You are correct that `405 Method Not Allowed` should not be related to permissions but instead means an incompatible request is being made (e.g. `POST` instead of `PUT`).

Comment: Some unsafe advice was offered by a now-deleted answer, and you may have a possible configuration issue that needs your attention. There is no contact info on your profile, so please reach out to [me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot?tab=profile).

Comment: Thanks Michael. I have resorted to just using the aws cli, using R to write out a bunch of batch files. It appears that I can't change the request as an argument in the aws.s3 R package.

Comment: Try running with `verbose = TRUE` to get more information. My guess would be a region issue. Does `bucketlist()` work?